# Changing CSS of A class after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying something like this. But it is not helping at all. I double checked that class name is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
for(var i=0, len=document.getElementsByClassName('xd_top_box').length;i<len;i++){
   document.getElementsByClassName('xd_top_box').style.display='inline-block';
}
});
</script>
```

I was trying to use jquery but then mixed it up with javascript. jQuery is shorter and much better I think.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have an odd mix of JS and jQuery. If you're loading jQuery you may as well use it. Secondly, `bind()` has been deprecated. You should use `on('load', fn)` instead.

Lastly the issue is because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object which you need to iterate over before updating the `style.display` of each individual element.

Try this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.xd_top_box').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer. It worked. Thanks for your expertise once again :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Like Rory mentioned, you want to use `$.on()` instead of `$.bind()` but if you wanted to use your original JS, you just need to reference the index of each element returned by `getElementsByClassName`

```css
.xd_top_box {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("xd_top_box");
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      box[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }
  });
</script>
<div class="xd_top_box">asdf</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MalikJunaidRasheed you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(document).ready()` method:

```
(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.xd_top_box').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And include a self closure to keep everything contained and variables from leaking out into other functions.